Jenkins linux Service Fails to Start with Exit Code .OpenJDK 11
I’m having trouble starting the Jenkins service on my server. When I run the command:
$ systemctl status jenkins
I get the following output:
× jenkins.service - Jenkins Continuous Integration Server Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/jenkins.service; enabled; preset: enabled) Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2024-09-26 05:17:31 UTC; 1min 12s ago Process: 3757 ExecStart=/usr/bin/jenkins (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) Main PID: 3757 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) CPU: 519ms 
What could be causing the Jenkins service to fail to start, and how can I resolve this issue? Any suggestions or additional troubleshooting steps would be greatly appreciated!
